# How to install Ubuntu 16.04 next to Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd

I've been trying to install ubuntu alongside windows 10 and it doesn't seem to work for me.

I read a lot of tutorials on askubuntu page, but it looks like I'm missing something.
I tried to install it with *something else* option because I wanted to make sure it goes to SSD. 
SSD=128GB, HDD=1TB

First, my laptop is brand new (no important data on it), windows 10 have been installed on SSD - I shrank it to 36GB. I have also shrunk windows partition on HDD to 20GB.
I went to power options in windows to uncheck fast startup.
I also went into boot manager to disable secure boot.

Then I ran installation process from USB and chose *something else*. I made partition on ssd EXT4 with mount point /.
On hdd, I created swap area (16GB), and EXT4 (/home). 
Device to boot loader installation: Windows Boot manager.

I continued with installation and after I rebooted computer it went straight into windows. I tried to boot it manually into ubuntu, but there is no such option. It seems that it can't recognize ubuntu installed.

After that, I went to windows to make free space on partitions again and ran installation again. This time, I chose *install ubuntu alongside windows*, but again it's not working.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

for your situation there you must change theboot files so you have the option to boot either on windows or ubuntu and to do that you have two choices:

First:

you install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) on windows and add the boot entery for ubuntu.

Second :

you use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) you download the iso , make a bootable stick then boot and choose "Recommended repair" and it will fix the problem for you.